# KnockoutJS - dependenant observables or computed observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there any difference between **dependenant observables** and **computed observables** in *KnockoutJS*?

My understanding is that **computed observables** are successors to **dependent observables** (basically just different name in the newer versions of Knockout) - but some of the tutorials on the web use one and some use the other.

Can someone answer this once and for all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same thing, the name was changed in knockout 2.0. Older examples may use the old name.

See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html

From Knockout's documentation:

> At runtime, ko.dependentObservable refers to the same function as
>   ko.computed, so your existing code will continue to work just fine.

Comment: oh, thanks.. Should have looked at the docs more closely! Will accept - in 8min :-)